# Question in probability- uniform distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, distribution-theory, uniform-distribution

I am struggling with a question in probability and I'd love to get some help.

It goes like this-

Given an infinite series of independent random variables $X_i$, so that for every natural $i\in \mathbb{N}$ $\,X_i\sim U([0,1])$.
We define $Y_i=X_i+X_{i+1}$

and $S_n= Y_1+...+Y_n$

1. Show using the chebyshev inequality that
   \begin{align*}
   \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{|S_n-n|}{n}=0
   \end{align*}
2. Use the chernoff bound to show that for every $a> 0$:

\begin{align*}
P(S_n\geq a)\leq e^{-a}(e-1)^{2n}
\end{align*}

for 1 I don't understand how can I use they chebyshev inequality to bound the actual expression and not just the probability.

for 2 I am not sure how to calculate the moment generating function (that is required for the chernoff bound) because consecutive $Y_i$ seem to be dependent of one another...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with the types of convergence and the relations between them ? (About question 1)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I think we very briefly learned in class (only a few minutes) about convergence of serises of random variables.

Comment: Evaluate the Expectation and the Variance of your variable. If it verifies the conditions of Chebyshev's inequality, then apply for a proper choice of $k$. You'll have the convergence in probability, and thanks to that, it implies a second mode of convergence, and you'll have a second result.

Comment: @Hamdiken Unfortunately I don't think I understand what you mean, I couldn't find anywhere in my notes any reference of second mode of convergence.
Also, are the different Yi independent random variables, or is it just that those with index difference bigger than 1 are independent?